# React Native iOS build failed : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm building an iOS app with React Native. Doing so, I installed a [react-native module](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc) and configured my iOS xcode project (cocoapods mainly) following the module tutorial. Now, when I run `react-native run-ios`, I get this error stack :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_JSNoBytecodeFileFormatVersion", referenced from:
>
> +[RCTJavaScriptLoader loadBundleAtURL:onProgress:onComplete:] in RCTJavaScriptLoader.o
>
> +[RCTJavaScriptLoader attemptSynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURL:runtimeBCVersion:sourceLength:error:] in RCTJavaScriptLoader.o
>     "facebook::react::IRemoteConnection::~IRemoteConnection()", referenced from:
>
> RemoteConnection::~RemoteConnection() in RCTInspector.o
>     "facebook::react::parseTypeFromHeader(facebook::react::BundleHeader const&)", referenced from:
>
> +[RCTJavaScriptLoader attemptSynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURL:runtimeBCVersion:sourceLength:error:] in RCTJavaScriptLoader.o
>
> "facebook::react::customJSCWrapper()", referenced from:
>
> -[RCTDevSettings isJSCSamplingProfilerAvailable] in RCTDevSettings.o
>
> -[RCTDevSettings toggleJSCSamplingProfiler] in RCTDevSettings.o
>         ____ZL11getInstancev_block_invoke in RCTInspector.o
>
> _RCTNSErrorFromJSErrorRef in RCTJSCErrorHandling.o
>
> -[RCTSamplingProfilerPackagerMethod handleRequest:withResponder:] in RCTSamplingProfilerPackagerMethod.o
>
> "facebook::react::systemJSCWrapper()", referenced from:
>
> -[RCTDevSettings isJSCSamplingProfilerAvailable] in RCTDevSettings.o
>
> -[RCTDevSettings toggleJSCSamplingProfiler] in RCTDevSettings.o
>
> _RCTNSErrorFromJSErrorRef in RCTJSCErrorHandling.o
>
> -[RCTSamplingProfilerPackagerMethod handleRequest:withResponder:] in RCTSamplingProfilerPackagerMethod.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> Ld /Users/antoine/R/devlab/ReactNative/medway-twilio/MedwayTwilio/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React/React.framework/React normal x86_64
>   (1 failure)

I suspect this is related to the inclusion of libraries and frameworks to the project with xcode, but I'm not sure.

This is a screenshot of my project target/build phases/link binary with libraries panel in xcode :

[image: Libraries]

Where "MedwayTwilio" is my project name

Comment: Can you show me more information, the part of library in you iOS project for example

Comment: Have you try to run react-native link ?

Comment: @JulienKode I added a screenshot if that's what you asked for. react-native link tells me my library is already linked

Comment: Can you add Pods_MedwayTwillo to Embedded Binaries ?

Comment: I just tried, did'nt change anything (but thanks for the idea ^^)

Comment: Have you try to stop your packager and type this:  watchman watch-del-all

Comment: rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Comment: rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*

Comment: Tried all this, doesn't work either ^^ really think it's about xcode config, can't figure what exactly

Comment: This is strange, I'll think about it

Comment: I think you have clean the derived data too

Answer (score 6):

Did you configured your CocoaPods dependencies as described [in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies)?

Also, you need to add a dependency on the RCTBatchedBridge subspec (if using 0.46) or RCTCxxBridge (if newer).

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    [...]
    'BatchedBridge', # Include if RN = 0.46
    'CxxBridge' # Include if RN >= 0.47
  ]
```

Comment: I don't see `'CxxBridge' # Include if RN >= 0.47` in the documentation

Comment: Adding the 'BatchedBridge' subspec fixed this issue for me.