# React native facebook login in ios undefined symbols for architechture x864

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I'm trying to add facebook login on react native latest version 0.49 by follow this tutorial
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

I did step by step and see some videos on youtube and did exactly but I still get the same 28 errors
[image]

I guess maybe it's because in the link Binary with Libraries I can't see the FBSDK, even I added it as explained on tutorial to Frameworks folder
[image]

I saw some posts in stack overflow e.g
[React Native iOS build failed : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550228/react-native-ios-build-failed-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

but without any help.
thanks.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 9 and used drag and drop to add frameworks in ypur project?

Comment: Yes, i drag the files from the downloaded facebook sdk and drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with XCode 9, where when you drag and drop any files, it does not get added to the target.
You need to manually add them to your target in File inspector now. 
[image]

This can happen not only with frameworks but other files as well. To prevent this issue, whenever you want to add any file or resource to your XCode project, you should first add that file/resource to the project folder and then right-click and then add to your XCode project using Add Files to ..

[image]

Comment: thanks you man, I spent whole day to find solution to this issue.